# Docker container can't connect to server running on localhost

Tags: python, docker, python-requests

I have a python file running a server:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import json

class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        with open('files.json') as myfile:
            self.wfile.write(myfile.read())

....

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, port=8080):
server_address = ('', port)
httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
print 'Starting httpd...'
httpd.serve_forever()
```

And another doing a get request:
    import requests

```
SESSION = requests.Session()
SESSION.trust_env = False

url = "http://localhost:8080"
response = SESSION.get(url)
data = response.json()
```

This works fine when I run the two normally. However when I containerise the app (not the server), requests throws this error at me:

```
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f7ec03e5ed0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

I assume this is because docker somehow prevents me from connecting to my server on localhost:8080?

Thanks for you help ☺

Comment: So the server is running on the host and the client runs in the container?

Comment: is 8080 on your local free?

Comment: Yes the server is running on host `python server.py`, and the client is in the container. And yes 8080 is free as the client can carry out the GET request just fine when not in the container.

Comment: If you have any questions about my answer, I'll extend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A container is meant to be an isolated environment. It's a "jail" for running processes protecting the host os. Think of containers as a virtual machine with its own ip address. `localhost` would be the container trying to connect to itself.

I'm guessing you could contact port 8080 on the host using its public ip address.

It would make more sense to run the server in docker. Then you can map a port in the server container to a port on your host. Then your client would work as expected.

The two most common ways a container can interact with the host os is:

- When mapping network ports from the container to to host
- When mapping files as volumes from the host into the container

It's fairly restrictive for very good reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have the server up and running as a container. How would I go about mapping a port in the server container to a port on my host? Is it using -P when building it?

Comment: If you are using `docker run` command you use the `-p` option. `-p 8000:8080` maps port 8080 from the container to 8000 on the host.

Comment: Do I need to add the `-p` option when running the client? Or do I have to change the url in the client to `url = "http://localhost:8000"`? My server is running, but when I go to `localhost:8080` it doesn't connect. Sorry about all the questions, I'm still a complete beginner to docker!

Comment: The client container needs to know what host name it can contact the server container. You use the `--link` option when you run the client container. There you can use the name or id of the server container and that will be the host name you connect to. You should really look into using `docker-compose` to make this a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I have it working now using link. I'm gonna have to look into docker-compose because I have a lot of containers running together haha.

Comment: @monadoboi Good stuff. It'd docker-compose or writing docker commands until your hands bleed. Seriously you can end up with 10+ line long instructions.